# Obtener tamaño de un vector en c++

Tags: c++

en el fichero .h de la clase habitación en la parte privada tengo un vector de otra clase:

```
vector<Mesa> mesas;
```

y desde el .cc de la clase habitación  hago un

```
tamano = mesas.size();
```

pero me dice: 'mesas' was not declared in this scope

Habitacion.h:

```
class Habitacion {

private:
  vector<Mesa> mesas;
Public:

fiend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Habitacion &h);
```

Habitacion.cc

```
#include "Habitacion.h"


ostream& operator <<(ostream &os, const Habitacion &h){

  tamano = mesas.size();
```

Comment: Podrías poner el código donde la declaras y el código que hace uso de la variable mesas. Pero básicamente es cuestión de  **ámbito** y **visibilidad**.

Comment: ya esta añadido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en que no utilizas el objeto de clase `Habitacion` para acceder a sus atributos.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const Habitacion &h) {
    tamano = mesas.size();    // Error
}
```

En esa instrucción, se intenta acceder al miembro `mesas` de la clase `std::ostream`, miembro que no existe, por lo que es normal que salte ese error.

Lo correcto sería:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const Habitacion &h) {
    tamano = h.mesas.size();    // OK
}
```

Comment: pero ahora me sale 'std::ostream& Habitacion::operator<<(ostream &os, const Habitacion &h)'  must take exactly one argument

Comment: No sé exactamente la lógica de tu aplicación, así que no sé lo que hace tu método, pero el operador `<<` ya existe, y lo único que estás haciendo es redefinirlo, por lo que ciertamente, tiene que tomar solo un único parámetro.

Comment: no te entiendo muy bien pero he vuelto a editar la pregunta

Comment: Error mío, no me había dado cuenta de que lo que hacías no era redefinir un método en tu clase, sino dar acceso a un método de otra clase a los atributos de la tuya.

Comment: entonces que tengo que hacer? tengo que dejar lo que me has dicho o lo dejo como antes? pero aun no funciona. PD: Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: no me habia fijado que no habias utilizado `h`. Ha sido una bola de errores tras otro míos, pero ya debería funcionar. A mí ya me funciona.

Comment: muchas gracias! ya funciona!